# How to make a visual bounce circle for record voice

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I want to make a UIView, circle, that scale based on volume of speak recording. I have this code to obtain the rate:

```
recorder.updateMeters()
let ALPHA = 0.05
let peakPower = pow(10, (ALPHA * Double(recorder.peakPower(forChannel: 0))))
```

How can I make this animation? I I make only:

```
self.audioCircle.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1+CGFloat(rate), y: 1+CGFloat(rate))
```

the animation is too static, I need a more natural bounce effect, how can I do?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`.transform` is what's implicitly animating your views change in size.

In that case, you should try using:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.75, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
    //update view
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: { (completed) in
    //animation completed    
})
```

The above animation might be what you want to use to animate your view. It gives a nice bounce effect, and you can play with the parameters to adjust it accordingly.

However, because of the nature of the input, I'm not sure how the animation will fare.

It might be best to update the audioCircle size every so often, as opposed to constantly. This would allow the animation time to preform both correctly and smoothly as opposed to rigidly.

Good luck.